# FedEx C# Sample Code Track Service Invalid Operation Unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fedex

I did a "download all" of the FedEx C# sample code, and loaded the Track Service>Track sln file.  I got some warnings when doing this, but moved forward.  I then ran the code, and immediately got the following error.  Please advise as to the solution.[image][image]

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'TrackWebServiceClient.TrackServiceWebReference.EMailNotificationEventType' to 'TrackWebServiceClient.TrackServiceWebReference.EMailNotificationEventType[]'

  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
       at TrackWebServiceClient.TrackServiceWebReference.TrackService..ctor() in C:\FedEx\TrackService_v10_cs\cs\TrackWebServiceClient\Track\Web References\TrackServiceWebReference\Reference.cs:line 43
       at TrackWebServiceClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\FedEx\TrackService_v10_cs\cs\TrackWebServiceClient\Track\Program.cs:line 16
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Your comments say it was build with VS2005.  Where did you get the code?  VS2005 is not compatible with VS2008 and newer.  The Net libraries are not compatible.

Comment: I downloaded it directly from Fedex developer resources.